# Trying to get pagination in my website Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I tried to follow this tutorial to add pagination in my website.
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/implement-bootstrap-pagination-with-spring-data-and-thymeleaf.html

But i get some errors
I cant figure out how to fix it

any help would be extremely appreaciated

```
Error creating bean with name 'shoesController': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'shoesService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shoesServiceImpl':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'shoesRepository'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'shoesRepository' defined in 
com.adminportal.repository.ShoesRepository defined in 
@EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.
EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: 
Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: 
Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.adminportal.repository.ShoesRepository
.findByPublishedIsTrueOrderByPublishedTimeDesc
(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! 
Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page
 com.adminportal.repository.ShoesRepository.findByPublishedIsTrueOrderByPublishedTimeDesc
(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! 
No property published found for type Shoes!;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 

Failed to create query for method public abstract
 
org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.adminportal.repository.ShoesRepository
.findByPublishedIsTrueOrderByPublishedTimeDesc(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
No property published found for type Shoes!
```

Here is my code

ShoesRepository.java

```
package com.adminportal.repository;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.adminportal.domain.Shoes;

public interface ShoesRepository extends CrudRepository<Shoes, Long>{
    
    Page<Shoes> findByPublishedIsTrueOrderByPublishedTimeDesc(Pageable pageable);
    
}
```

ShoesService.java

```
package com.adminportal.service;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;

import com.adminportal.domain.Shoes;



public interface ShoesService {
    Shoes save(Shoes shoes);
    
    List<Shoes> findAll();
    
    Shoes findOne(Long id);
    
    Page<Shoes> getAllPublishedPosts(Pageable pageable);
    
}
```

ShoesServiceImpl.java

```
package com.adminportal.service.impl;



import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.adminportal.domain.Shoes;
import com.adminportal.repository.ShoesRepository;
import com.adminportal.service.ShoesService;


@Service
public class ShoesServiceImpl implements ShoesService{

    
    @Autowired
    private ShoesRepository shoesRepository;
    
    public Shoes save(Shoes shoes) {
        return shoesRepository.save(shoes);
    }
    
    public List<Shoes> findAll() {
        return (List<Shoes>)shoesRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Shoes findOne(Long id) {
        return shoesRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Shoes> getAllPublishedPosts(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Shoes> shoesList = shoesRepository.findByPublishedIsTrueOrderByPublishedTimeDesc(pageable);
        return shoesList;
    }

    
    
}
```

ShoesController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/manageProducts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String manageProductsGet(Model uiModel, Pageable pageable) {
        
        PageWrapper<Shoes> page = new PageWrapper<Shoes>
            (shoesService.getAllPublishedPosts(pageable), "/manageProducts");
        uiModel.addAttribute("page", page);
        return "manageProducts";
    }
```

manageProducts.html

```
 <div class="pages" th:fragment='paginationbar'>
    <ul class="pagination">
    
    <li class="previous" th:class="${page.hasPrevious}? '' : 'disabled'">
        <span class="page-link" th:if="${not page.hasPrevious}">&#10094;</span>
        <a class="page-link" th:if='${page.hasPrevious}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page.page=${page.number-1},page.size=${page.size})}' >&#10094;</a>
      </li>
    
   <li th:each="item : ${page.items}' th:class='${item.current}? 'active' : ''">
        <span class="page-link" th:if='${item.current}' th:text='${item.number}'>1</span>
        <a class="page-link" th:if='${not item.current}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page.page=${item.number},page.size=${page.size})}'><span th:text='${item.number}'>1</span></a>
      </li>
    
    <li th:each="item : ${page.items}' th:class='${item.current}? 'active' : ''">
        <span class="page-link" th:if='${item.current}' th:text='${item.number}'>2</span>
        <a class="page-link" th:if='${not item.current}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page.page=${item.number},page.size=${page.size})}'><span th:text='${item.number}'>1</span></a>
      </li>
    <li th:each="item : ${page.items}' th:class='${item.current}? 'active' : ''">
        <span class="page-link" th:if='${item.current}' th:text='${item.number}'>3</span>
        <a class="page-link" th:if='${not item.current}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page.page=${item.number},page.size=${page.size})}'><span th:text='${item.number}'>1</span></a>
      </li>
    
     
    <li class="nextpage" th:class="${page.hasNext}? '' : 'disabled'">
        <span class="page-link" th:if='${not page.hasNext}'>&#10095;</span>
        <a class="page-link" th:if='${page.hasNext}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page.page=${page.number+1},page.size=${page.size})}' title='Go to next page'>&#10095;</a>
      </li>
      
     
    </ul>
    
    
    
    </div>
```

Shoes.java

```
package com.adminportal.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Entity
public class Shoes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String size;
    private String category;
    private double price;
    private boolean active=true;
    
    @Column(columnDefinition="text")
    private String description;
    private int inStockNumber;

    
    @Transient
    private MultipartFile shoesImage;
    
    
    

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }


    


    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public MultipartFile getShoesImage() {
        return shoesImage;
    }

    public void setShoesImage(MultipartFile shoesImage) {
        this.shoesImage = shoesImage;
    }

    public int getInStockNumber() {
        return inStockNumber;
    }

    public void setInStockNumber(int inStockNumber) {
        this.inStockNumber = inStockNumber;
    }

    

}
```

Comment: Before checking the source completely, i notice you have the wrong import for Pageable. Fix that and reframe your question. 
`import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable`

Comment: I changed it I still get an error

Comment: The error is that spring data has failed to create a query for the method `ShoesRepository.findByPublishedIsTrueOrderByPublishedTimeDesc`  because it didn't find a property `published ` in the class `Shoes`. Could you post the `Shoes` class source code.

Comment: i see, i just added it rn!

Comment: @Cirrus If my answer helped you consider accepting it as the answer so that it can be ”closed” and others can benefit from. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is that spring has failed to create the bean `ShoesRepository` because the method `ShoesRepository.findByPublishedIsTrueOrderByPublishedTimeDesc` expect an attribute called `published` in the entity `Shoes` which doesn't exist.

The interface `CrudRepository` expose only methods for Create, Update, Read or Delete operations, not for pagination.

since you would like to use pagination, you have to use `PagingAndSortingRepository` or `JpaRepository` that adds additional methods to ease paginated access to entities:
You can read more here [spring-data-documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts)

You have to remove the method `findByPublishedIsTrueOrderByPublishedTimeDesc`)
So you have to change your repository as:

```
public interface ShoesRepository extends JpaRepository<Shoes, Long> {
}
```

You have to change `ShoesServiceImpl.getAllPublishedPosts` implementation to :

```
@Override
public Page<Shoes> getAllPublishedPosts(Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Shoes> shoesList = shoesRepository.findAll(pageable);
    return shoesList;
}
```

The method `shoesRepository.findAll` is exposed by the `PagingAndSortingRepository` and its implementation will be generated automatically at runtime by spring data.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply but this doesnt work for me, i dont get any errors but the list of my product doesnt show up in my website and i get an empty website with the pagination (with only one page tho)